# Cocos2d-x 3.0 Project showing error during Appstore Validation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0

Here is the snippet:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>English</string>
 <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
 <string>MowDown</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>MowDown</string>
 <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
 <string>Icon-57.png</string>
 <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
 <array>
  <string>Icon-29</string>
  <string>Icon-80</string>
  <string>Icon-58</string>
  <string>Icon-120</string>
  <string>Icon.png</string>
  <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
  <string>Icon-57.png</string>
  <string>Icon-114.png</string>
  <string>Icon-72.png</string>
  <string>Icon-144.png</string>
 </array>
 <key>CFBundleIconFiles~ipad</key>
 <array>
  <string>Icon-29</string>
  <string>Icon-50</string>
  <string>Icon-58</string>
  <string>Icon-80</string>
  <string>Icon-40</string>
  <string>Icon-100</string>
  <string>Icon-152</string>
  <string>Icon-76</string>
  <string>Icon-120</string>
  <string>Icon.png</string>
  <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
  <string>Icon-57.png</string>
  <string>Icon-114.png</string>
  <string>Icon-72.png</string>
  <string>Icon-144.png</string>
 </array>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.logan.mowdown</string>
 <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>MowDown</string>
 <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>APPL</string>
 <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>1.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
 <string>????</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1</string>
 <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
 <array/>
 <key>UILaunchImages</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>8.0</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
   <string>Default</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
   <string>Portrait</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
   <string>{320, 480}</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>8.0</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
   <string>Default-568h</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
   <string>Portrait</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
   <string>{320, 568}</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>8.0</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
   <string>Default-667h</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
   <string>Portrait</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
   <string>{375, 667}</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>8.0</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
   <string>Default-736h</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
   <string>Portrait</string>
   <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
   <string>{414, 736}</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
 <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
  <string>gamekit</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have just finished a project in cocos2d-X v3.0, But When I want to submit it to appstore it is showing an error during validation phase.

Error Message is

> "unable to validate your application.The Package does not contain an
>   Info.plist"

I have checked some solutions from various forums.But those did not work for me.

Please help me.

---

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once. In my case the problem was leaving in blank Build field in General>Identity section of my target.

Check if you're setting Version and Build number in this section

[image]